# rails 5 ForbiddenAttributesError on bulk operations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

i try to bulk operation in my rails controller this is my script

```
def update_by_user
    user_skill_selected = UserSkillSelected.create(params[:user_skill_selected][:users])

    # check through array if all is valid
    if user_skill_selected.all? {|item| item.valid?}
      render json: {json_status: save_success}
    else
      render json: {json_status: save_failed}
    end
end
```

and this is my user_skill_selected_params

```
def user_skill_selected_params
    params.require(:user_skill_selected).permit(:user_id, :subskill_id, :skill_id, :users => [])
  end
```

unfortunately i get an error in my log, the log said

```
"exception": "#<ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError:ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError>",
```

after that i try to bulk operations from rails console with using create method with the array value and its work

can anyone solve this... :(
sorry for the bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be confusing. Your code is passing in `params[:user_skill_selected][:users]` to the model `create` method, instead of your `user_skill_selected_params` strong parameters, which is why you're seeing that error.

Change this line:

```
user_skill_selected = UserSkillSelected.create(params[:user_skill_selected][:users])
```

To this:

```
user_skill_selected = UserSkillSelected.create(user_skill_selected_params)
```

And it should eliminate this error.

Comment: i just need users params in my user_skill_selected_params. i just want pass this  [
        {
            "user_id": 54,
            "subskill_id": 20,
            "skill_id": 3
        },
        {
            "user_id": 54,
            "subskill_id": 17,
            "skill_id": 3
        },
        {
            "user_id": 54,
            "subskill_id": 23,
            "skill_id": 4
        }]  to my UserSkillSelected.create

Comment: ok its work with this    def update_by_user
    user_skill_selected = UserSkillSelected.create!(user_skill_selected_params[:users])

    # check through array if all is valid
    if user_skill_selected.all? {|item| item.valid?}
      render json: {json_status: save_success}
    else
      render json: {json_status: save_failed}
    end
  end